# Discard changes made to single local file with Github

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have made some changes to my local index.html and to other files.

I don't need the changes to my index.html and I just want to pull all the new code from the server:

```
C:\G>git pull origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': xx
Password for 'https://xx':
remote: Counting objects: 21, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), done.
From https://github.com/xx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   59be7d8..083e776  master     -> origin/master
Updating 59be7d8..083e776
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        WebUserApp/index.html
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

C:\G\abilitest-user>git stash WebUserApp/index.html
usage: git core\git-stash list [<options>]
   or: git core\git-stash show [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash [save [--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                       [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]]
   or: git core\git-stash clear

C:\G>
```

The error message don't help me at all.  Can someone give me advice on what to do ? How can I tell git to forget about changes to my local index.html so I can just pull and download from the server.  I don't mind if I overwrite my index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to keep those changes at all, do a git checkout on the particular file(s)

```
git checkout WebUserApp/index.html
```

This will bring back the `index.html` to the state of the last commit on the branch. If you already added those changes using `git add WebUserApp/index.html`, you can un-add those using `git reset HEAD WebUserApp/index.html`

---

If you want to remove them temporarily, and re-apply them later, use git stash (which you are not using correctly, currently)

```
git stash
```

Once you've done the pull/merge, you can apply your changes back using

```
git stash pop
```

Note that git stash stashes changes across all tracked files which are modified, so it doesn't take in any file arguments unlike what you were providing in `git stash WebUserApp/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any uncommitted changes in your local file, you can just discard them by using -f option with checkout:

```
git checkout -f
```